# Improvement in java maps management

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

Hi everyone this is the question

I have something like that

```
private Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map1 = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Double>>();
private Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map2= new HashMap<String, Map<String,Double>>();
private Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map3= new HashMap<String, Map<String,Double>>();
```

Map1, Map2 and Map3 are of the same type, but depending on factors the data will be agrupated in those maps.

Then I have this code to put the data on each map, acording to the discrimnatign factor

```
private void doSomething(data){
    if(factor1){
       map1.put(data);
       functionForData(map1);
    }
    else if(factor2){
       map2.put(data);
       functionForData(map2);
    }
    else if(factor3){
       map3.put(data);
       functionForData(map3);
    }
}
```

I think this isn't the better approach to handle the data and determine which map will store the information, specially because I have to repeat all the code for the functionForData() only changing the map that I need.
How can I improve this? 
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Assign the proper map to a reference in the if-else blocks.  Then after you've determined the proper map reference, call `put` and `functionForData` once, with the reference.

Comment: is functionForData common for all maps?
what is factor exactly?
what is the purpose of 3 maps?
what data will be?

Comment: I receive list with mixed values, I have 3 maps for group them into a subgroup with common properties.

Answer (score 0):

This addresses your "duplication of code" issue:

```
private void doSomething(data, Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map1) {
      map.put(data);
      functionForData(map);
}

private void doSomething(data){
    if(factor1){
       doSomething(map1);
    }
    else if(factor2){
       doSomething(map2);
    }
    else if(factor3){
       doSomething(map3);
    }
}
```